# Find schema name given table name in Redshift

Tags: sql, select, amazon-redshift, where-clause, information-schema

Is it possible to retrieve the schema name given the table name in redshift and return an error if table is not found?

`SELECT * FROM PG_TABLE_DEF WHERE tablename = 'tablename';`

doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`pg_table_def`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_PG_TABLE_DEF.html) lets you see only the tables that are visible to your curent user - which, presumably, is not the case of the table you are searching for.

You could use [`pg_tables`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_join_PG.html) instead (this is originally a Postgre catalog view, that is documented as *partially accessible* in Redshift):

```
select schemaname from pg_tables where tablename = 'mytable';
```

You might also be facing some case issue, if your table was created with a case-sensitive identifier. In that case:

```
where lower(tablename) = 'mytable';
```

Comment: actually, it is not working. For one of my tables in `public` schema it returns `invalid operation: column "schema_name" does not exist in pg_tables;` why is searching for `column`?

Comment: works if I remove underscore `_`.  For my version of redshift, it is: `select schemaname from pg_tables where tablename = 'mytable';`

Comment: @SumitSidana: sorry that was a typo. Fixed